# How to convert some words in a sentence into a link?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, tags

This is an example of creating links in a string using react. Most of the examples I found were my manipulating dom so after so messing around I figured out how to do it.

```
function profile() {
  const hashtagRegex = /\B(\#[a-zA-Z]+\b)(?!;)/gm;
  const { fullName, userName, image, bio } = userProfileData;
  const bioMatch = bio && bio.match(hashtagRegex);
  const editbio = bio && bio.split(" ");
  bioMatch &&
    editbio.map((word, index) => {
      if (word.match(hashtagRegex)) {
        editbio[index - 1] = editbio[index - 1] + " ";
        editbio[index] = <a href="https://google.com">{word}</a>;
      } else {
        editbio[index] = " " + word;
      }
    });
  return (
    <div className="profile">{editbio}</div>
  );
}
```

If you add spacing directly to the array index it converts the link into `[object][object]` and if you try to join in the return it does the same so this worked for me. If someone has a better way to do it, please share.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to link the website to the text if you are trying to do it with HTML would be

```
<p><a href="link">word</a></p>
```

Comment: The whole point is dynamically doing if from the data coming from the database or API. DOing statically is not the point